# Set default settings application Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show user my settings application. To do that, user must select application in Preference Dialog. I have been successful until i install my app into a 6.0.1 version. It used to work well with 4.4.2 version.

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.SettingsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.settings.SETTINGS"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This code is I used before, I changed it like this but result is the same

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.SettingsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.settings.SETTINGS"></action>
                <action android:name="android.settings.DISPLAY_SETTINGS"></action>
                <action android:name="android.settings.HOME_SETTINGS"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Can anyone help me with which action should I use or is it blocked by Android System after 6.0.1 devices?